# php-curl ubuntu server64bit (12.04)

Tags: curl, 64-bit, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install php5-curl on my ubuntu-server 64bit but it said like this

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-curl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

In one of the forum, I found that it is because of incificcent disk space .So,I tried this command.

df -Th

Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      ext4      462G  283G  157G  65% /
udev           devtmpfs  2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     791M  3.1M  788M   1% /run
none           tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs     2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm

Seem to be many availabe space yet but still can't process

I already tried apt-get install clean && upgrade/update

Nothing help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this first:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If it does not work:

Uninstall php5 and try:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Force remove package (if needed)

```
sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq <package name>
```

Try install php5 again.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install <package name>
```

Comment: thanks Casper, I did like what you said , now ubuntu is showing me this

Comment: W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/07/automatically-install-missing-ppa-gpg-keys-with-one-command-or-your-money-back/ i never tried this... Have you managed to install php-curl?

Comment: when I tried to install PHP5-Curl //The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-curl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 2):

i encountered this problem. I only need to update my repositories and installed curl (installed through synaptic) and it went smoothly.